# How do I use a PHP File as a Section

Tags: php, html, apache2, php-7

I have a folder with the files index.php and AdminSite.php. How can I now display AdminSite.php with the Query String "domain.com/index.php?section=admin/" ?

(If My Grammar is not correct please correct me :D)

Comment: Do you want to display AdminSite.php as a section in index.php? You could just include it in.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you, it works :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional and [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file.

```
if(!empty($_GET['section']) && $_GET['section'] == 'admin/') {
     include 'AdminSite.php'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (assuming that AdminSite.php is in the same directory with index.php):

```
<?php
    $section = $_GET['section'];

    if($section && $section == 'admin'){
        include('AdminSite.php');
    }
?>
```

If you're going to do this to other sections, then it can be something like this:

```
<?php
    $section = $_GET['section'];

    if($section){
        switch($section){
            case 'admin':
                include('AdminSite.php');
                break;
            case 'contacts':
                include('Contacts.php');
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Or like this:

```
<?php
    $section = $_GET['section'];

    $sections = [
        'admin' => 'AdminSite.php',
        'contacts' => 'Contacts.php',
        // add your sections here
        // 'section from url' => 'path to file'
    ];

    if($section && file_exists($sections[$section])){
        include($sections[$section]);
    }
?>
```